# How can I access a value when inserting into a table?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a java sql query, the simplified table would be table(name,version) with a unique constraint on `(name, version)`.

I'm trying to insert a row into my database with a conditional statement. Meaning that when a entry with the same name exists, it should insert the row with same name and its version increased  by 1.

I have tried with the following:

```
INSERT INTO table(name,version) 
VALUES(?, CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT name from table where name=?)
THEN (SELECT MAX(version) FROM table WHERE name = ?) +1
ELSE 1 END)
```

values are sent by user.

My question is, how can I access the 'name' inside the values so I could compare them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write this as a single query:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, version) 
    SELECT ?, COLAESCE(MAX(t2.version) + 1, 1)
    FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.name = ?;
```

That said, this is dangerous.  Two threads could execute this query "at the same time" and possibly create the same version number.  You can prevent this from happening by adding a unique index/constraint on `(name, version)`.

With the unique index/constraint, one of the updates will fail if there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the name before insertion. In your case, if something went wrong then how would you know about it so you get the name before insert query.

Not sure but you try this:

```
declare int version;
if exists(SELECT name from table where name=?)
then
version = SELECT MAX(version) FROM table WHERE name = ?
version += 1
else
version = 1
end
```

Regards.

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. Please mention the database product for which this works.

Comment: Yes, @a_horse_with_no_name you are right but it is only the suggestion so he may get some directions.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two approaches:
1. For each pair of name and version you first query the max version:

```
SELECT MAX(VERSION) as MAX FROM <table> WHERE NAME = <name>
```

And then you insert the result + 1 with a corresponding insert query:

```
INSERT INTO <table>(NAME,VERSION) VALUES (<name>,result+1)
```

This approach is very straight-forward, easy-to-read and implement, however, not really performant because of so many queries necessary.

2. You can achieve that with sql alone with sql analytics and window functions, e.g.:

   `SELECT NAME, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) as VERSION FROM<table>`

You can then save the result of this query as a table using `CREATE TABLE as SELECT...`
(The assumption here is that the first version is 1, if it is not the case, then one could slightly rework the query). This solution would be very performant even for large datasets.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I dont think I've expressed myself clearly enough. the ? in values is a placeholder (I think that's what it's called in postgres). So when the user sends the example request I.e name = horse, version=2, the ? gets replaces by 'horse' but im not able to access this value in the following CASE statement. when I run it with the example in the question ( where name = ?) I get the error that not enough query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bad plan, you might be changing what the user's specified data. That is likely to not be what is desired,  maybe they're not trying to create a new version but just unaware that the one wanted already exists. But, you can create a function, which your java calls, not only inserts the requested version or max+1 if the requested version already exists. Moreover it returns the actual values inserted.

```
-- create table
create table nv( name text
               , version integer
               , constraint nv_uk unique (name, version)
               );   

-- function to create version or 1+max if requested exists 
create or replace function new_version 
                         ( name_in text
                         , version_in integer
                         )
 returns record
 language plpgsql strict
 as $$
declare 
     violated_constraint text;
     return_name_version record;
 begin 
     insert into nv(name,version) 
          values (name_in,version_in) 
       returning (name, version) into return_name_version;
     return return_name_version;

exception 
   when  unique_violation
   then  
         GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS violated_constraint = CONSTRAINT_NAME;
         if violated_constraint like '%nv\_uk%'
         then 
             insert into nv(name,version)
                  select name_in, 1+max(version)
                    from nv
                   where name = name_in
                   group by name_in
               returning (name, version) into return_name_version;
             return return_name_version;
         end if;
end; 
$$;     

-- create some data
insert into nv(name,version)              
   select 'n1', gn
     from generate_series( 1,3) gn ;

-- test insert existing 
select new_version('n2',1);
select new_version('n1',1);

select * 
  from nv
order by name, version;
```